# How should I grab data one by one from excel and print with loop function using python and store it in list

Tags: python

**I have data like this in an excel sheet.
Want to get the company name on the list?**
[image]

Comment: Welcome - as written, your question doesn't give enough information as to what it is you want an answer to. We see your data, but how do you want it transformed, and what python code have you tried? If you're looking to work with Excel, `pandas` might be a good starting place.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, and replace the filename and sheet name with yours:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook(filename='111.xlsx', read_only=True)

ws = wb['Sheet1']

data = []
for row in ws.rows:
    for cell in row:
        data.append(cell.value)

print(data)
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

First install `pandas` library with the below command:

```bash
➜ pip install pandas
```

Then running below code snippet you can print the values of `Company name` column row by row and add them to a list called `values`:

```py
import pandas as pd

values = []
df = pd.read_excel('sample.xls', 'Sheet1')
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    company_name = row["Company Name"]
    print(company_name)
    values.append(company_name)

print(values)
```

Also, you can do this with `xlrd` but just for *.xls* files, So install `xlrd` library with the below command:

```bash
➜ pip install pandas xlrd
```

Then with running below code snippet you can print the values of `Company name` column row by row and add them to a list called `values`:

```py
from xlrd import open_workbook

values = []

wb = open_workbook('<your_excel_file_name>.xls')
for sheet in wb.sheets():
    # print('Sheet:',sheet.name)
    
    for row in range(sheet.nrows):
        value  = sheet.cell(row,sheet.ncols(1)).value
        print(value)
        values.append(value)

print(values)
```